# AttributeMapMetadata in Dynamics CRM 4.0

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-4, microsoft-dynamics

How to fetch Metadata with type [AttributeMapMetadata](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb959809.aspx)?

I have tried this piece of code:

```
foreach (CrmMetadata metadata in CrmMetadata.CrmMetadata)
{
   if ((metadata as AttributeMapMetadata) != null)
   {
      var whatIneed = (AttributeMapMetadata)metadata;
   }
}
```

... but unfortunately without any success. CrmMetadata's memebers are already of type "EntityMetadata". I just want to have a list with Attribute mappings. How to reach this goal correctly?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

So, it looks CrmMetadata is of type RetrieveAllEntitiesResponse. I'm right? [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc151212.aspx) is an example, how to work with class.

```
foreach (CrmMetadata metadata in CrmMetadata.CrmMetadata)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < metadata.Attributes.Length; j++)
    {
      // Get Current Attribute.
      currentAttribute = metadata.Attributes[j];

      Type attributeType = currentAttribute.GetType();

      if (attributeType == typeof(AttributeMapMetadata))
      {
        var whatIneed = (AttributeMapMetadata)currentAttribute;
      }
    }
}
```